# How to Convert Uri? data type to Uri

Tags: android, kotlin

I am initializing uri so that i can access it from anywhere

`private var myuri:Uri? = null`

now in Oncreate Method

```
Oncreate{
   button.setOnClickListner{
   uploadfile(filename, myuri)
   }
}
fun uploadfile(filename:String, fileuri:uri){
  .
  .
  .//some code
}
```

there is an error says

> Type Mismatch required Uri found Uri?

I cannot change anything from uploadfile function
and i have to access myuri throughout this kotlin file.

Comment: `myuri?.let{  uploadfile(filename, it) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is supposed to happen if it is still null?

If you are SURE it cannot be null the moment you are calling it, just use:

```
myuri!!
```

If you want it to throw an exception, use:

```
myuri ?: throw Exception
```

Otherwise if you want nothing to happen, when its null, as already suggested by yourself, use:

```
myuri?.let{...}
```

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
myuri?.let{ uploadfile(filename, it) }
```